# When I add a blank page to my document, I got "resourceDictionary is null" when I try to merge it

Tags: java, apache, pdf, pdfbox

I want to merge my docs for duplex print. When I app blank page to my document, I got an exception.

**Exception:**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: resourceDictionary is null
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDResources.<init>(PDResources.java:70)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFMergerUtility.appendDocument(PDFMergerUtility.java:552)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFMergerUtility.mergeDocuments(PDFMergerUtility.java:261)
    at mergePdf.MergePdf.main(MergePdf.java:67)
```

**My code:**

```
    try {
        pdf = new PDFMergerUtility();
        for(String inputDoc: inputDocs) {
            File inputFile = new File(inputDoc);
            if (douplexPrint) {
                pdfDoc = new PDDocument();
                pdfDoc = PDDocument.load(inputFile);
                if (pdfDoc.getNumberOfPages() % 2 != 0) {
                    pdfDoc.addPage(new PDPage());
                    pdfDoc.save(inputFile);
                }
                pdfDoc.close();
            }
            pdf.addSource(inputFile); 
        }

        pdf.setDestinationFileName(outputDoc);
        pdf.setDestinationStream(output);
        /* 67 */ pdf.mergeDocuments(MemoryUsageSetting.setupMainMemoryOnly());
        writeToFile(outputDoc, output.toByteArray());

    }
```

Comment: What PDFBox version are you using? The current one is 2.0.13.

Comment: I use 2.0.13 version

Comment: I don't think so, or you have several versions in your classpath. Because the call `new PDResources()` in PDFMergerUtility.java:552 existed only from 22.4.2016 to 2.5.2016 on that line number. And in August 2016 that bug was fixed: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3473

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Thank you! Than it!

Comment: Glad to hear that… please answer the question yourself, or delete it :-)